# Why does my obsidian boat sink?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I played the new Minecraft snapshot 15w14a, and I saw a obsidian boat in my creative inventory. I put it in the water, but it sank immediately.

Why does my obsidian boat sink?

Comment: Didn't realize you were talking about the base game. Mostlikely it is not completly functinally yet or an April fool.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is an April Fool's joke.

Answer (score 1):

After realiasing you were talking about the base game not the FORGE-Mod I found [this](https://mojang.com/2015/04/minecraft-snapshot-15w14a-the-love-and-hugs-update/) Article.

When checking all the content I am sure it is an April Fool's Day post.

> We have removed the ability to directly harm other creatures. You should be rewarded for helping, not hurting.

Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Nope, they sink in lava - I mean molten cheese - too!

Comment: @joppiesaus edited ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's made out of obsidian...? per chance?

can't imagine that's the most *buoyant* element in the Minecraft world

Comment: So? Iron isn't buoyant and we can create boats out of that. Also: it's a game, buoyancy has nothing to do with the materials it is made out of

Comment: I can see you don't quite grasp satire.